# Entity Framework SQL projection to class model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Am I doing it wrong ir it is not possible to project a certain data model to strongly typed model instead of anonymous object?

I have this Linq expression:

```
var kudosLogsQuery = _kudosLogsDbSet
    .Include(log => log.Type)
    .Include(log => log.Employee)
    .Where(log =>
        log.OrganizationId == options.OrganizationId &&
        log.BasketId == null)
    .Where(StatusFilter(options.Status))
    .Where(TypeFilter(options.TypeId))
    .Where(UserFilter(options.SearchUserId))
    .Select(log => new Comment 
     { 
         Id = log.Id, 
         Created = log.Created,    
         Employee = new Employee 
         { 
             FirstName = log.Employee.Name 
         }
         Type = new Type
         {
             Name = log.Type.Name
         }
    })
    .OrderByDescending(log => log.Created)
    .ToList()
```

TypeFilter, StatusFilter, UserFilter is either x => true or just an another filter by Status, Type or User.

Unfortunately it produces an SQL statement that takes all fields from that table and projects it on the application side. The conclusion was made by testing these Linq expressions on SQL profiler.

Question:
Am I doing something wrong, or SQL projection works with anonymous objects only?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Class an Entity type in your Context?

Comment: No it is not. I forgot to clarify this, Comment object is not an Entity type, it is just a simple object with properties, like a Data Transfer Object.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior on linqpad with EF6. In this case the sql query is correct from ctx.Set<T>(). What is/how do you get, dbSet in your sample ?

Comment: Like @tschmit007, can't reproduce - VS2015 EF6

Comment: Move the projection further down the chain so that the Order, Skip, Take is working off the database instead of your custom object?  Also, why include Type if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: I have edited the post because as I tried a few examples my self they were ok. This is the exact expression I cant get it working as I would expect.
Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @DasBoot, did you try to remove includes? It should work without those ones.

Comment: Actually I tried removing Includes and Where statements with those custom filters except the first one and it worked. I returned back includes and it still worked, but after returning even the first Where(StatusFilter(options.Status)) it started Selecting all Columns again. And I am not sure why, because for this specific case all those filters were x => true. Does it really ruin everything?